# Preserve colored output using php's popen

Tags: php, popen, terminal-color

When using `popen` in php, is there a way to preserve the colored output a program might generate? Is there maybe a way I can tell the shell to print all color escape sequences, instead of resolving them?

Comment: Are you doing this in a PHP script, or on the command line?

Comment: I am running a php script on the command line that is executing a program that uses color escape sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the program you are calling. Usually, if a program supports coloured output, it would ask the OS, "am I running on a terminal?" If yes, then it outputs colour codes. If not, it won't. If you run that program through `popen()`, then the OS would say "no, you're not running on a terminal" and the program would choose not to output the colour codes (because they would be confusing in the captured output).

Some programs may have an option to *force* the output of colour codes even if output is not being written to a terminal. However, that is not something you can force externally if the program doesn't already have a way to do it.

Comment: That answers all my questions! Thanks.

Comment: If you're using GNU utils like `ls`, the force argument is `--color=always`.