# Symfony Process Eats Terminal Control Codes

Tags: symfony, vt100, symfony-process

So I'm running a Symfony `Process` for some commands, and I noticed that when I write those to Symfony's `OutputInterface` it is not showing colors or progress bars. I think that the commands (npm, artisan, ls, etc) are using [terminal control codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#background_coloring), and one of those classes is eating the non-standard ASCII characters.

EDIT:
I've done some digging and I belive Symfony uses its `StreamOutput` class by default. It appears to be able to output in color, and I've tried telling it to `OUTPUT_RAW`. No beans there. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else...

Is there a built-in way to tell these classes not to do that? How can I get my pretty output back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors availability [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838541/preserve-colored-output-using-phps-popen) on the program you are calling. 
You may try to set the tty/pty:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) 
{
    $process = new Process('ls -l --color="always"');
    $process->setTty(true); // or $process->setPty(true);
    $process->run();
    $output->write($process->getOutput());
}
```

See related [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17010).

I don't think that a command output removes the escape codes. Next example works well (for me):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->write(shell_exec('ls -l --color="always"')); // ok, output is colored
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! They really should note what the implication of `setTty` is; noobs like me might not realize that TTY means a 'teletype terminal' without a lot of digging into the subject.